# Install imagemagick with delegates on debian

Tags: svg, debian, imagemagick, png, jpeg

I installed imagemagick on Debian using this guide: https://www.tecmint.com/install-imagemagick-on-debian-ubuntu/.
When I run `identify image.png` it gives this error: `` identify: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572. ``
What is the correct way to install imagemagick with jpeg, png, svg, tiff and other file formats support?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you want to use Magick 7? Debian has a ready-to-use `imagemagick.deb` package based on 6.9 that will install all needed dependencies automatically.

Comment: You are right, I solved this problem by installing the package. Thank you

Comment: Since you mentioned delegation for SVG, be sure to install either librsvg or Inkscape, the internal SVG interpreter is seriously sub-standard.